# StackSmashing not detected due to buggy code

Tags: c

In a .C file in main() function, in my project running on QNX7.

```
void BufferOverflow(char* name)
{
    char buffer[5];
    strcpy(buffer,name);
}
func_main()
{
    char buffer[256];
    int i = 0;  
    for (i=0;i<256;i++)
        buffer[i] = 'A';
    BufferOverflow(buffer);
}
```

I compiled this with following options in make file.

```
C_CLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now,-z,noexecstack -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O1 -pie -fPIE -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all
```

But on running this , I am getting "Aborted", instead of getting "StackSmashing detected".

But same thing if I run as a separated executable and run it on same h/w I can get "StackSmashing".

Can any body help as why this difference is.. ?

Comment: WeIl I guess C_CLAGS have about the same effect as C_BLAGS, C_RLAGS or C_ZLAGS.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. At least C_CLAGS makes a surprised face. Is that a typo?

Comment: `C_CLAGS`-> `C_CFLAGS` ?

Comment: @prasant you will want to change `C_CLAGS` to `CFLAGS`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Normally people use CFLAGS, no underscore, so that would be two typos. Or maybe there are more if these typos and they cancel themselves out. How should we know without seeing the entire makefile?

Comment: the stackframe is 5*char + 8 bytes + argument by reference, so it should be 17 byte on the stack, yes [assuming 4 byte for argument]? my guess it that you write into main or even into _start(). try doing a smaller overflow

Comment: It's worth checking that you're defining the right variable in your `Makefile`. Copy-paste the name if necessary to avoid a near miss.